# Error when trying to save a captured image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, photos

In my project, I am capturing an image. But when it starts saving the image, app crashes with the error of -

> "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping"

My code is as follows-

```
//  Library Assets
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
    var photoAsset: PHFetchResult!

    let saveImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)

                if let actualSaveImage = saveImage {
                //  Save image
                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

                    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(actualSaveImage)
                    let assetPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photoAsset)
                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
                    self.buttonCapture.hidden = false
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.lastShotFlag = false
                    }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                        NSLog("\nSave Image -> %@", (success ? "Success" : "Error!"))
                })
                }
                else {
                    NSLog("\nProblem in saveImage. It's nil.")
                }
```

After debugging it looks like I am not getting any value for the constant **albumChangeRequest**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have never given `self.assetCollection` or `self.photoAsset` any value, so they are nil. Thus, when you try to use them in your PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest initializer, you crash.

By the way, if all you want to do is save the image into the camera roll, you don't need all that code. The creation request alone is all you need.

Or, if you want to save the image into the camera roll and into an album, you don't need to call `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection:assets:)` to do it.

Finally, you really shouldn't have all that extra stuff in the change block. Just do the change and no more. The other stuff should be in the completion block.

Comment: Thanks mate! Only the creation request did the saving. But it saves to the camera roll whereas I wanted to create a new album for my app.

Comment: Any idea how can I give any value to those variables. I thought they should automatically get value according to the current state of the new album. And I added 3 photos in the new album so that they won't be nil. But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: "But it saves to the camera roll whereas I wanted to create a new album for my app." Okay! So I guess maybe you should ask a question about that (how to create a new album), because there is nothing at all in your code that would cause that to happen - I would never in a million years have guessed that album creation was in your mind (and the system can't guess it either)...